# Running Storybook on older project?

Tags: angular, webpack, storybook

This is a long shot, but maybe someone has some ideas.

I am trying to install Storybook on an older version of an angular App. The app is running Angular 5 with Ionic 3, webpack 3.

I need to find a way to install storybook onto it, however i cant get it to install the latest version because that depends on webpack 4, i cant update webpack because that will break the app. Refactoring the entire app isn't currently a possibility.

I have tried to install older versions of Storybook though that just throws up different errors installing. Let alone whatever errors may appear once its installed.

In a perfect world i need to install the latest version of Storybook into the project to take advantage of the new features it offers (especially Angular support)

It was suggested i could try and run parallel webpack versions, one which storybook uses to keep it happy and another for the rest of the app, however i am not even sure if that's possible (to run 2 versions side by side).

Any suggestions would be welcomed :)

UPDATE:
With the latest version (which seems to be all i can get to install at the moment) i get this error when starting.

> 10% building 1/1 modules 0 active(node:6060) DeprecationWarning:
>   Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
>   (node:6060) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.apply is deprecated. Call
>   apply on the plugin directly instead
>
> TypeError: compilation.templatesPlugin is not a function